# EF Code First An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have a problem for which lots of answers exist. The exception I've gotten says:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

As I've surfed the web and stack over flow pages, I've reached to this point that the instance of the DbContext should be only one in each UnitOfWork or the previous one must be detached. It sounds reasonable! But, my problem is that I have no idea where in my code (posted below) I have to place the modifications.
I've been trying to use Generic Repository and Unit of Work pattern plus EF code first approach.

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected DbContext EntityContext;
    protected readonly IDbSet<T> DbSet;

    protected Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        EntityContext = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetList()
    {
        return DbSet.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        return DbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

The generic Unit of Work:

```
public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private DbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int Commit()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing) return;
        if (_context == null) return;

        _context.Dispose();
        _context = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

The client repository

```
public class ClientRepository : Repository<Client>, IClientRepository
{
    public ClientRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }

    public override Client Add(Client entity)
    {
        return DbSet.Add(entity); // <-- Here the exception comes
    }
}
```

This is the main part of the 'GenerateClients' method placed inside the 'DataGenerator' project.

```
var countries = container.Resolve<ICountryService>().GetList().ToList();

        if (!countries.Any())
        {
            throw new InvalidDataGeneratorException(Strings.NoCountryToCreateClient);
        }

        var clientService = container.Resolve<IClientService>();

        clientService.Create(new Client
                             {
                                 Name = "Dell",
                                 CountryId = countries[0].Id,
                                 Country = countries[0],
                                 AddressLineOne = "76-98 Victoria Street",});
```

And here the ClientService which uses the ClientRepository:

```
public class ClientService : Service<Client>, IClientService
{
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
    private readonly IClientRepository _clientRepository;
    private readonly ICalculatorService _calculatorService;

    public ClientService(IClientRepository clientRepository,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        ICalculatorService calculatorService)
        : base(clientRepository, unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _calculatorService = calculatorService;
        _clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }

    public override void Create(Client client)
    {
        _clientRepository.Add(client);
        _clientRepository.Save();
    }

    }
```

Please note that some of the methods have been removed in order to minimize the length of the question.

Actually, when I run my Data Generator project which is of type Console, preceding to adding Clients, a number of Countries have been added with no problem, but as it comes to the Client service and it goes down into the ClientRepository, the exception raises up.

I don't know where should I place the modifications to avoid the exception. Many thanks

Comment: What's the calling code look like that throws the error

Comment: I do not know if this related the issue or not, but your IDisposable implementation in UnitOfWork is far from the correct pattern. For example you have no destructor (or just left from the code sample?), so GC.SupressFinalize makes no sense... Please google for IDisplosable design pattern.

Comment: @3dd: the calling code if I get what you mean correctly is the part of code I've added to the question (the last part). First, I get the list of countries and then for each of which a new client is to be generated.

Comment: @g.pickardou: I guess what you've said could be problematic as well. Actually, the Resharper also tells me what you've mentioned. I don't know but may be if I correct it, that would help

Comment: What I meant was something is using `ClientRepository` what does that code look like

Comment: @3dd: I've added the ClientService which calls the ClientRepository to the question and that's all I have.

Comment: Are you injecting the instances of `IClientRepository` and `IUnitOfWork` and are you injecting them as singletons

Comment: Yes am injecting the instances but not as singletons.. If that should be implementing, the singleton I mean, it must be added in the GenericRepository constructor, do you think so?

Comment: No not at all, I'm just looking for the reason why Add is called for an entity with the same key,  or an entity that has been loaded in the context already. Are you somewhere looping over a list and calling `Create` multiple times

Comment: Well.. preceding to adding clients there is a methods which generates a list of countries using a loop. But all of them are created with success. Then, when it comes for generating new clients there is no loop out there. But the `Create` methods is called multiple times. But am note sure if it brings the problem as the exception raises as the first client is to be added!

Comment: does `Client` have a relation to country and are you adding it as `Client.Country = RELATED_COUNTRY` perhaps it's trying to add the same country twice, I usually use `Client.CountryId = ID_OF_COUNTRY`

Comment: OMG..!! you've made my Day! Yes.. you know every country can have one or more clients and every client belongs to only one country. I've defined the `Country` as a virtual property in the model of `Client` and wrongly that is assigned in the `CreateClient` service which I guess there is no Need for that; simply assigning the related `CountryId` can do the job! And well done! Many thanks for your efforts..

Comment: Please make an answer by your last comment I'll vote you up! (if you like of course)

Comment: Pleasure man, glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does Client have a relation to country and are you adding it as `Client.Country = RELATED_COUNTRY` perhaps it's trying to add the same country twice, I usually use `Client.CountryId = ID_OF_COUNTRY`